# Brushless DC motor terminal inductance

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I am working on designing a reaction wheel using a BLDC motor.

Ho w can I calculate the terminal inductance (in H) for a brushless DC motor with the following properties:

```
Brand name: Racerstar 
Item name: AirA 2508 brushless motor 
KV: 1200KV
Thread: CW
Configuration: 12N14P
Internal resistance: 72mΩ
Shaft diameter: 4mm
Motor dimensions: φ31.5*35mm
AWG: 20#200mm
Cable length: 200mm
Weight(Incl. cables): 50g
Weight(Excl. cables): 46g
No. of cell(Lipo): 4-6S
Idle current@10V(A): 0.9A
Max continuous power(W)180S: 802W
Max continuous current(A)180S: 34.7A
```

Answer (score 5):

You can not calculate inductance from the information given. You will need to measure it or get it from the motor manufacturer. If the manufacturer doesn't publish inductance they are unlikely to publish anything else that will be helpful in determining inductance.